# PyQt5. Открытие файла с помощью программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

У меня есть программа на *PyQt5* (блокнот). Я хочу чтобы при открытии файла `.txt` текст из него автоматически попадал в `QTextEdit`. Как это сделать?

Comment: парсить текст файла и записывать в textEdit, в чем проблема?

Comment: Именно чтоб файл открывал программу, а не открытие файла в уже открытой программе(пользователь кликает по файлу и открывается программа)

Comment: Это проблема операционной системы, какую программы запустит, не Питона или PyQt.

Comment: @MarianD т. е. ос сама поймёт что ей нужно вставить текст из файла в определённое поле?

Comment: Конечно, нет. Но вы хотите открыть файл в ОС, а не в вашей программе, если я хорошо понял. И ОС не спустит вашу программу, пока ее это каким-то образом не подскажете. И когда ее это подскажете, нужно ее подсказать тоже, с какими параметрами она должна запустить вашу программу (одним — может быть единственным —  параметром будет имя файла — что-то как `%1` в зависимости от ОС). И ваша программа нужна в соответствии с этим параметром начитать соответствующий файл и показать его в QTextEdit.

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю, почему вы не показали какая у вас есть программа на PyQt5(блокнот).

Я понял вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

editorProgram = 'notepad'                                            # notepad

class ListenWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListenWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button_listen = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбрать файл', self)
        font1 = self.button_listen.font()
        font1.setPointSize(10)
        self.button_listen.setFont(font1)
        self.button_listen.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.button_listen.clicked.connect(self.startToListen)

        self.v_box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_box1.addWidget(self.button_listen)

    def startToListen(self):
        file, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
                        'Open File', 
                        './', 
                        'py Files (*.py);;Text Files (*.txt)')
        if not file:
            return

        process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        process.start(editorProgram, [file])

        self.setEnabled(False)
        process.finished.connect(lambda: self.setEnabled(True))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ListenWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('notepad file-listener')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ТимонЯблоков что не так?